# Factoring in rectification voltage drop when calculating ideal DC current

Tags: voltage, current, rectifier, ideal

Under ideal circumstances, there would be no voltage drop across a rectifier. I wanted to know if it was possible to calculate ideal DC current when a load is connected to the rectifier.

For the following circuit below, would it be possible to calculate the ideal DC current if you offset the DC voltage by the 1.3V drop experienced across the rectifier?

In the real world, I have measured the voltage across the load to be 205.3mV which results in a current of 3.7mA. Is it possible to calculate using theory? Or is a high precision op-amp rectifier required as it exhibits 0 voltage drop.

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to perform an idealized calculation for a perfect (no voltage drop) bridge rectifier? Wouldn't the voltage at the capacitor would just follow the rising input once the input reaches the point where the load has brought it from the prior half-cycle? And after the peak follow the declining voltage until the rate of change of the input source exceeds the rate of change implied by the load, at which point it would track an RC decline curve? Or is there something else in this question I'm missing?

Comment: (1.3 V is pretty low for the forward voltage of a "sub-MHz range" rectifier - Schottky?) Something is off with a mA current where (RMS?) voltage equals load resistance in Ohms. `voltage across the load to be 205.3mV` Voltmeter set to DC or AC? Oscilloscope? I'd expect considerably more than 50 Watts…

Comment: I will assume that you measure 205.3 mV AC ripple on the 51.6 ohm load. If the 51.6 V input is its peak value, the DC voltage on the output will be about 50 VDC after dropping about 1.6 V through the rectifiers. The current will be a little less than 1 A. However, in real life, the AC source will probably have some internal resistance that will result in voltage drop. Why not just use a simulator to get the values you seek?

Answer (score -1):

Well, notice that the output voltage of an ideal bridge rectifier (in steady state) with a known voltage drop across the rectifier is given by:

$$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_\text{r}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\right)}{\text{CR}}\right)&\space\text{when}\space\displaystyle0\le\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\right)<\tau\\
\\
\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_\text{r}\right)\left|\displaystyle\cos\left(2\pi\text{f}\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\right)\right)\right|&\space\text{when}\space\displaystyle\tau\le\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\right)<\frac{1}{2\text{f}}
\end{cases}\tag1$$

Where \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the AC-voltage source, \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$ is the amplitude of the AC-voltage source, \$\text{V}_\text{r}\$ is the voltage drop across the brigde rectifier and \$\tau\$ is the solution to equation \$(2)\$ in the range \$\displaystyle\tau\in\left(\frac{1}{4\text{f}},\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\right)\$:

$$\exp\left(-\frac{\tau}{\text{CR}}\right)=-\cos\left(2\pi\text{f}\tau\right)\tag2$$

Using your values, we get:

$$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(t\right)\approx\begin{cases}
\displaystyle50.3\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{282000}\right)}{0.0516}\right)&\space\text{when}\space\displaystyle0\le\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{282000}\right)<3.533072175\cdot10^{-6}\\
\\
50.3\left|\displaystyle\cos\left(282000\pi\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{282000}\right)\right)\right|&\space\text{when}\space\displaystyle3.533072175\cdot10^{-6}\le\text{mod}\left(t,\frac{1}{282000}\right)<\frac{1}{282000}
\end{cases}\tag3$$

Finding the RMS-value of the output voltage we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}&=\sqrt{2\text{f}\int\limits_0^\frac{1}{2\text{f}}\text{V}_\text{o}^2\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_\text{r}}{2}\cdot\sqrt{2+4\text{f}\left(\text{CR}\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{2\tau}{\text{CR}}\right)\right)-\tau\right)-\frac{\sin\left(4\pi\text{f}\tau\right)}{\pi}}\\
\\
&=\frac{503}{20} \sqrt{\frac{145512}{5}\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{5000 \tau}{129}\right)\right)-564000 \tau-\frac{\sin (564000 \pi  \tau)}{\pi }+2}\\
\\
&\approx50.29828024\space\text{V}
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}

So, we get:

$$\text{I}_\text{R}=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}}{\text{R}}\approx0.9747728729\space\text{A}\tag5$$